# Patriot Missile Floating Pointing Error

Tags: floating-point, binary

From Computer System: A Programmer's Perspective http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu

Practice Problem 2.51

We saw in Problem 2.46 that the Patriot missile software approximated 0.1 as x =

```
0.00011001100110011001100(binary).
```

Suppose instead that they had used IEEE round-to-even mode to determine an approximation x′ to 0.1 with 23 bits to the right of the binary point.

A. What is the binary representation of x′?

```
from the solution at the back of book, 
Looking at the nonterminating sequence for 1/10, we can see that the 2 bits to the right of the rounding position are 1, and so a better approximation to 1/10 would be obtained by incrementing x to get x′ = 0.00011001100110011001101, which is larger than 0.1.
```

B. What is the approximate decimal value of x′ − 0.1?

```
The solution says it's

We can see that x′ − 0.1 has binary representation: 0.0000000000000000000000000[1100]
Comparing this to the binary representation of 1 , we can see that it is 2^−22 × 0.1 , which is around 2.38 x 10^-8
```

My question for (B) is that how do we get

```
x' - 0.1 == 0.0 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000[1100] ?
```

my calculation gives me 0.000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0100 (about twice what the solution says)

Answer (score 1):

0.1 in *fractional binary representation* is: 0.000[1100]

For the approximation in question 2.46 there was a *cutoff* after position 23, and in question 2.51 a *round to even* happens at position 23. The latter means: - either 1) go to the nearest value - or 2) if exactly in the middle, go to even. As position 24 ff is `11001100...` it's case 1) and the nearest value is when position 23 becomes 1. Bits of original value and approximations:

```
x     = 0.0001100110011001100110011001100110011001100...
x_246 = 0.00011001100110011001100  # cutoff
x_251 = 0.00011001100110011001101  # round to even - as asked in A)
```

The difference `x' - 0.1`, i.e. `x_251 - x`, as asked in B)

- fractional binary

  ```
  x_251:   0.00011001100110011001101
  x:     - 0.0001100110011001100110011001100110011001100...
  fdiff:   0.0000000000000000000000000110011001100110011... or
  fdiff:   0.0 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000[1100]

  --> this answers "question for (B) is that how do we get x' - 0.1 
        == 0.0 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000[1100]"
  ```
- decimal value

  ```
  ddiff = (1*2^-26 + 1*2^-27) + (1*2^-30 + A1*2^-31) + (...) + ...
        =     3*2^-27         +     3*2^-31         +    3*2^-35 + ...
        = 0.1*2^-22 = 2.384e-8  (sum of geometric serie)
  julia> @printf "%.40f" 0.1*2.0^-22
  0.0000000238418579101562513234889800848443
  ```

---

Aside: why the difference between `julia> @printf "%.40f" 0.1f0` and the decimal difference ddiff above?

```
0.1000000014901161193847656250000000000000
0.0000000238418579101562513234889800848443
```

`0.1f0` is represented as an *IEEE Floating Point value*. The bits (`julia> bits(f0.1f0)`) ("00111101110011001100110011001101") have the following meaning:

```
0 01111011 10011001100110011001101
| |        | M = 1 + f
| | E = e - Bias = 123 - 127 = -4 --> V = M*2^-4 (right shift M by 4)
| sign

M:         1.10011001100110011001101
M/sh: 0.0001.10011001100110011001101
x_shifted: 0.000110011001100110011001101
x_251:     0.00011001100110011001101
```

--> the shifted approximation for 0.1 has 4 more bits than x_251. Decimal value of difference `x_shifted - x` (calculated as above) give: 0.1*2^-26. Now the two representations fit:

```
    julia> @printf "%.40f" 0.1*2.0^-26
    0.0000000014901161193847657077180612553028
    0.1000000014901161193847656250000000000000  # julia> @printf "%.40f" 0.1f0
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Julia

A.

```
julia> bits(0.1f0)
"00111101110011001100110011001101"
```

B. We can't compute the difference exactly (as there is no native decimal type), but you can print the decimal exactly, and subtract manually

```
julia> @printf "%.40f" 0.1f0
0.1000000014901161193847656250000000000000
```

So the difference is `0.0000000014901161193847656250000000000000 = 1.490116119384765625e-9`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same confusion. You could try to understand the given solution by thinking backwards from the solution.

0.1 + `the given solution`

= `0.000 1100 1100 1100...` + `0.00000000000000000000000001100 1100 1100...`

= `0.000 1100 1100 1100 1100 1100 1111 1111 1111...`

Observe that the above result is the best we can do to **approximate** x' = `0.000 1100 1100 1100 1100 1101`.